# imovie. Adding a static image without the gentle zooming effect

Tags: imovie, macos

I'm using imovie 10.0.3

When I add a static image (a jpeg file) to my movie it adds a gentle zooming effect. Very pretty but I didn't want it, and I cannot work out how to switch it off. Infuriating!

I'm trying to add the image either by dragging it onto the movie, or by clicking the [+] button which appears on the photo. Either way it adds it with a zooming effect.

Within the movie I notice I can select it, and then use an "Adjust" toolbar to achieve various things (mostly colour shifts in the image)... but I can't see any options for disabling the effect.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the Adjust toolbar, click Crop, then Fit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's the correct answer. I think that must be the only button and menu option in the entire i-move interface that I didn't try :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, this effect is, indeed, infuriating!

Comment: There are many different websites that say to set the "dissolve/zoom" effect in picture in picture to 0 when trying to add an image (which has text) anywhere in the video. That + removing Ken Burns effect seems to fix any animation of the image

Answer (score 8):

In Preferences, Photo Placement is by default set to "Ken Burns". Set it to something else and you'll avoid this annoyance.

Comment: This is also a correct answer.

Comment: As of MacOS 13 (Ventura), "Preferences" is renamed to "Settings".
Click iMovie -> "Settings", or Cmd+, shortcut.